# how to get url which is open into browser using python

Tags: python-3.x, networking, browser, web-traffic

I want to get all the url which is currently open into webbrowser how can i get that using python 3.

for example in my browser currently open https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask this url i want this url into my python console,Can any one help me how can I get this.
Thank you in advance

I refer https://pusher.com/tutorials/web-traffic-monitor-python but I want this using core python

Answer (score 0):

That seem impossible to achieve, unless you modify your browser source code or install a malicious add-on on it. The reason is that any modern OS will keep a separate memory space for each program running in the machine, so python can't access to memory of the browser.

Implementing a web traffic monitor won't help in the moment the browser use https urls.